# FindAndUpdate How to check if document was really updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Imagine the following model:

```
var Office = 
{
    id: 1,
    name: "My Office",
    branches: 
    [
      {
        adddress: "Some street, that avenue",
        isPrincipal: true,
      },
      {
        adddress: "Another address",
        isPrincipal: false,
      },      
    ]
}
```

I'd like to remove a branch, but we can't let the user remove the principal branch from an office. So here's my function:

```
remove: function(body)
{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
  {
    return Office.findByIdAndUpdate(1, { $pull: {'branches': {_id: body.branch.id}}}, { new: true })
    .then(function(updatedOffice){
      resolve(updatedOffice)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      reject(error);
    });

  })
}
```

I have some doubts here:

1. As you can see I haven't included the another WHERE on the isPrincipal property, this is because I don't know how can I determine whether the office object got actually changed. Because the object will alway be retrieved but... How can I know this for sure?
2. Is FindByIdAndUpdate the best approach considering we can't let a user delete the principal branch, and if he's trying to do so, we have to show a warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only real reliable way to see if an update was applied for something like a [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) is to basically check the returned document and see if the data you intended to [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) is still in there or not.

That's for any of the [`"findAndUpdate"`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) variety of actions, and there is a valid reason for that as well as it also being the case that a plain [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) will actually "reliably" tell you if the modification was in fact made.

To walk through the cases:

### Check the Returned Content

This basically involves looking at the array in the returned document in order to see if what we asked to remove is actually there:

```
var pullId = "5961de06ea264532c684611a";

Office.findByIdAndUpdate(1,
  { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": pullId } } },
  { "new": true }
).then(office => {
  // Check if the supplied value is still in the array
  console.log(
    "Still there?: %s",
    (office.branches.find( b => b._id.toHexString() === pullId))
      ? true : false
  );
}).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

We use [`.toHexString()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html#toHexString) in order to compare the actual value from an `ObjectId` since JavaScript just does not do "equality" with "Objects". You would check on both "left" and "right" if supplying something that was already "cast" to an `ObjectId` value, but in this case we know the other input is a "string".

### Just use .update(), "It's reliable"

The other case here to consider brings into question if you "really need" the returned modified data anyway. Because the [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) method, will reliably return a result telling you if anything was actually modified:

```
Office.update(
  { "_id": 1 },
  { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": pullId } } },
).then(result => {
  log(result);
}).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Where `result` here will look like:

```
{
  "n": 1,
  "nModified": 1,        // <--- This always tells the truth, and cannot lie!
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "6440673063762657282",
    "t": 4
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000004",
  "ok": 1
}
```

And in which the `nModified` is a "true" indicator of whether something "actually updated". Therefore if it's `1` then the `$pull` actually had an effect, but when `0` nothing was actually removed from the array and nothing was modified.

This is because the method actually uses the updated API, which does have reliable results indicating actual modifications. The same would apply to something like a [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) which did not actually change the value because the the value supplied was equal to what already existed in the document.

### findAndModify Lies!

The other case here you might think of when looking closely at the documentation is to actually inspect the "raw result" and see if the document was modified or not. There is actually an indicator in the specification for this.

The problem is ( as well as requiring more work with Promises ) that the result is not actually truthful:

```
var bogusId = "5961de06ea264532c684611a"; // We know this is not there!

Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  Office.findByIdAndUpdate(1,
    { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": bogusId } } },
    { "new": true, "passRawResult" },
    (err,result,raw) => {        // We cannot pass multiple results to a Promise
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({ result, raw });   // So we wrap it!
    }
  )
})
.then(response => log(response.raw))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The problem here is that even when we "know" this should not modify, the response says otherwise:

```
{
  "lastErrorObject": {
    "updatedExisting": true,
    "n": 1                     // <--- LIES! IT'S ALL LIES!!!
  },
  "value": {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "My Office",
    "branches": [
      {
        "address": "Third address",
        "isPrincipal": false,
        "_id": "5961de06ea264532c6846118"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "_kareemIgnore": true
}
```

So even after all that work to get the "third" argument out of the callback response, we still did not get told the correct information about the update.

---

### Concluding

So if you want to "reliably" do this with a single request *( and you **cannot** reliably do that with multiple requests since the **document could change** in between! )* then your two options are:

1. Check the returned document to see if the data you wanted to remove is still there.
2. Forget returning a document and trust that [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) always tells you the "truth" ;)

Which one of these you use depends on the application usage pattern, but those are the two different ways of returning an "reliable" result.

---

### Bit of a Listing

So just to be sure, here's a listing that goes through all the examples and demonstrates what they actually return:

```
const async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

const branchesSchema = new Schema({
  address: String,
  isPrincipal: Boolean
});

const officeSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String,
  branches: [branchesSchema]
},{ _id: false });

const Office = mongoose.model('Office', officeSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

const testId = "5961a56d3ffd3d5e19c61610";

async.series(
  [
    // Clean data
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    // Insert some data and pull
    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          // Create and demonstrate
          (callback) =>
            Office.create({
              _id: 1,
              name: "My Office",
              branches: [
                {
                  address: "Some street, that avenue",
                  isPrincipal: true
                },
                {
                  address: "Another address",
                  isPrincipal: false
                },
                {
                  address: "Third address",
                  isPrincipal: false
                }
              ]
            },callback),

          // Demo Alternates
          (office,callback) =>
            async.mapSeries(
              [true,false].map((t,i) => ({ t, branch: office.branches[i] })),
              (test,callback) =>
                (test.t)
                  ? Office.findByIdAndUpdate(office._id,
                      { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": test.branch._id } } },
                      { "new": true , "passRawResult": true },
                      (err,result,raw) => {
                        if (err) callback(err);
                        log(result);
                        log(raw);
                        callback();
                      })
                  : Office.findByIdAndUpdate(office._id,
                      { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": test.branch._id } } },
                      { "new": true } // false here
                    ).then(result => {
                      log(result);
                      console.log(
                        "Present %s",
                        (result.branches.find( b =>
                          b._id.toHexString() === test.branch._id.toHexString() ))
                          ? true : false
                      );
                      callback();
                    }).catch(err => callback(err)),
              callback
            )
        ],
        callback
      ),

    // Find and demonstate fails
    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback) => Office.findOne({},callback),

          (office,callback) =>
            async.eachSeries([true,false],(item,callback) =>
              (item)
                ? Office.findByIdAndUpdate(office._id,
                    { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": testId } } },
                    { "new": true, "passRawResult": true },
                    (err,result,raw) => {
                      if (err) callback(err);
                      log(result);
                      log(raw);
                      callback();
                    }
                  )
                : Office.findByIdAndUpdate(office._id,
                    { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": testId } } },
                    { "new": true }
                  ).then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log(
                      "Present %s",
                      (result.branches.find( b =>
                        b._id.toHexString() === office.branches[0]._id.toHexString()))
                        ? true : false
                    );
                    callback();
                  })
                  .catch(err => callback(err)),
              callback)

        ],
        callback
      ),

    // Demonstrate update() modified shows 0
    (callback) =>
      Office.update(
        {},
        { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": testId } } }
      ).then(result => {
        log(result);
        callback();
      })
      .catch(err => callback(err)),

    // Demonstrate wrapped promise
    (callback) =>
      Office.findOne()
        .then(office => {
          return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            Office.findByIdAndUpdate(office._id,
              { "$pull": { "branches": { "_id": testId } } },
              { "new": true, "passRawResult": true },
              (err,result,raw) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(raw)
              }
            );
          })
        })
        .then(office => {
          log(office);
          callback();
        })
        .catch(err => callback(err))

  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

And the output it produces:

```
Mongoose: offices.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: offices.insert({ _id: 1, name: 'My Office', branches: [ { address: 'Some street, that avenue', isPrincipal: true, _id: ObjectId("5961e5211a73e8331b44d74b") }, { address: 'Another address', isPrincipal: false, _id: ObjectId("5961e5211a73e8331b44d74a") }, { address: 'Third address', isPrincipal: false, _id: ObjectId("5961e5211a73e8331b44d749") } ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: offices.findAndModify({ _id: 1 }, [], { '$pull': { branches: { _id: ObjectId("5961e5211a73e8331b44d74b") } } }, { new: true, passRawResult: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "My Office",
  "__v": 0,
  "branches": [
    {
      "address": "Another address",
      "isPrincipal": false,
      "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d74a"
    },
    {
      "address": "Third address",
      "isPrincipal": false,
      "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d749"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "lastErrorObject": {
    "updatedExisting": true,
    "n": 1
  },
  "value": {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "My Office",
    "branches": [
      {
        "address": "Another address",
        "isPrincipal": false,
        "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d74a"
      },
      {
        "address": "Third address",
        "isPrincipal": false,
        "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d749"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "_kareemIgnore": true
}
Mongoose: offices.findAndModify({ _id: 1 }, [], { '$pull': { branches: { _id: ObjectId("5961e5211a73e8331b44d74a") } } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "My Office",
  "__v": 0,
  "branches": [
    {
      "address": "Third address",
      "isPrincipal": false,
      "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d749"
    }
  ]
}
Present false
Mongoose: offices.findOne({}, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: offices.findAndModify({ _id: 1 }, [], { '$pull': { branches: { _id: ObjectId("5961a56d3ffd3d5e19c61610") } } }, { new: true, passRawResult: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "My Office",
  "__v": 0,
  "branches": [
    {
      "address": "Third address",
      "isPrincipal": false,
      "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d749"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "lastErrorObject": {
    "updatedExisting": true,
    "n": 1
  },
  "value": {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "My Office",
    "branches": [
      {
        "address": "Third address",
        "isPrincipal": false,
        "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d749"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "_kareemIgnore": true
}
Mongoose: offices.findAndModify({ _id: 1 }, [], { '$pull': { branches: { _id: ObjectId("5961a56d3ffd3d5e19c61610") } } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{ _id: 1,
  name: 'My Office',
  __v: 0,
  branches:
   [ { address: 'Third address',
       isPrincipal: false,
       _id: 5961e5211a73e8331b44d749 } ] }
Present true
Mongoose: offices.update({}, { '$pull': { branches: { _id: ObjectId("5961a56d3ffd3d5e19c61610") } } }, {})
{
  "n": 1,
  "nModified": 0,
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "6440680872013201413",
    "t": 4
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000004",
  "ok": 1
}
Mongoose: offices.findOne({}, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: offices.findAndModify({ _id: 1 }, [], { '$pull': { branches: { _id: ObjectId("5961a56d3ffd3d5e19c61610") } } }, { new: true, passRawResult: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{
  "lastErrorObject": {
    "updatedExisting": true,
    "n": 1
  },
  "value": {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "My Office",
    "branches": [
      {
        "address": "Third address",
        "isPrincipal": false,
        "_id": "5961e5211a73e8331b44d749"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "_kareemIgnore": true
}
```

Comment: This is such a dedicated answer. Let me thank you, I finally went to the findByIdAndUpdate and then checking for the existence of the object. THANK YOU MASTER!

Answer (score 0):

Finding and updating in two steps would better in this case, as you just said you'll have the option of warning the user.

A note on find. You have an array of objects `branches`. To match more than one field in `find` [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) is needed. The query will look something like:

```
Office.findOne({_id: 1, "branches" : {$elemMatch: {"_id": body.branch.id, "isPrincipal": false}}})
```

Which will either return the office document or not. If it does, you proceed with `findByIdAndUpdate` (which is better than modifying and saving the already found document). If it does not, return a forbidden message to the user.

Comment: So there's a big problem with what you propose here. That put simply is as a "separate" request you have no way of ensuring that nothing else modified the document in between the "modification" and your proposed "later read". Another process could have modified the document in that timeframe, and there are actually a few methods to tell if the "update" actually changed something or not.

Comment: I proposed `find` then `update`, not the other way around. So, "later read" part is confusing. In any case, your proposed `update` way is much better, as it takes care of "allowed" or "forbidden" with one request :)

Comment: The order does not matter. It's not reliable. You should actually read what I wrote on this and learn something.

Comment: Did twice. I actually mentioned your way is better which means I've read it. Might as well delete my answer.