# MongoDB - check if $addToSet was a duplicate or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm creating a like functionality for my app using MongoDB. I recently stumbled upon a problem.

My code for the liking:

```
async function like(articleId, userId) {
const db = await makeDb();
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const result = db.collection(collectionName).findOneAndUpdate(
    { articleId: ObjectID(articleId) },
    {
      $setOnInsert: {
        articleId: ObjectID(articleId),
        creationDate: new Date()
      },
      $addToSet: { likes: ObjectID(userId) }
    },
    { upsert: true }
  );
  resolve(result);
});
```

What it does:

1. If there is no document in the collection create one and fill in all the fields
2. If a document exists update only the `likes` array with a new userID

This works as expected and there are no problems, thanks to `$addToSe`t I don't have any duplicates etc.

However after the above code gets executed and the `result` is returned I need to do some additional stuff and for it to work I need to know if Mongos `$addToSet` did change anything.

So in short:

1. if a new userId has been added to the `likes` array I want to do something
2. if the userId is already in the `likes` array and the `$addToSet` didnt change anything I don't want to take any action.

Is there a way to distinguish if the `$addToSet` did something?

The current `console.log()` of the result looks like this:

```
  { 
    lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: true },
    value: { _id: 5e2c47c57bb5183d80dce14f,
             articleId: 5da4d1365217baf52fbcd76a,
             creationDate: 2020-01-25T13:51:01.928Z,
             likes: [ 5d750b677d8edfc08af8a527 ] 
    },
    ok: 1 
  }
```

The one thing that comes to my mind (but is very bad performance-wise) is to compare the `likes` array before the update if it contains the userID with javascript `includes` method.

Any better ideas?

Comment: So you wanted to ensure `addToSet` has not deleted/changed any other elements in array apart from adding new unique userID or just not adding it if it's a duplicate ? So it does not affect existing duplicate elements/elements in the array..

Comment: @srinivasy I think none of the above :P I just want to know IF the `addToSet` did anything. The `addToSet` works ok, the thing is there are two options:

1. I want to add user X, user X is NOT in the likes  array, `addToSet` updates the object by adding user X, return updated object.
2. I want to add user X, user X is in the likes array, `addToSet` has no effect, return updated (in this case same as old) object.

I want to distinguis between those two situation and react on them differently. 

So if (1.) happens I want to do something, but if (2.) happens I don't want to do anything.

Comment: So from the output of query you get ` n: 1, updatedExisting: true` through which you can get to know if it updated or not, So addToSet pushed a new element or not !!

Comment: Yeah... I though exactly the same but sadly for some weird reason thats not the case, it's always returning `{ n:1 and  updatedExisting: true }` even if `addToSet` did nothing :(

Comment: Maybe it's reflecting to nMatched but not to nUpdated

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

99% of the credit goes to `Neil Lunn` for this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994382/2175228

It brought me on the right track. I ditched the `findOneAndUpdate` method in favor of the `updateOne` method. The query parameters etc. everything stayed the same, only the method name changed and obviously the result type of this method.

The problem with the `updateOne` method is that it does not return the object that was updated (or the old one). But it does return the `upsertedId` which is the only thing I need in my situation.

So in the end what You get is a very long `CommandResult` object which starts with:

```
 CommandResult {
  result: { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 },
  (...)
 }
```

but when I looked very closely I noticed that the object has exactly those fields that I needed the whole time:

```
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null, // if object was inserted, this field will contain it's ID
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
```

So what You need to do is just take the parts that You need from the `CommandResult` object and just proceed ;)

My code after the changes:

```
async function like(articleId, userId) {
    const db = await makeDb();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection(collectionName)
        .updateOne(
          { articleId: ObjectID(articleId) },
          {
            $setOnInsert: {
              articleId: ObjectID(articleId),
              creationDate: new Date()
            },
            $addToSet: { likes: ObjectID(userId) }
          },
          { upsert: true }
        )
        .then(data => {
          // wrap the content that You need
          const result = {
            upsertedId: data.upsertedId,
            upsertedCount: data.upsertedCount,
            modifiedCount: data.modifiedCount
          };

          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }
```

Hopefully this answer will help someone with a similar problem in the future :)

Comment: Yes, yes. Most splendid. Thank You for documenting this. I'm the someone from the future and it helped.